# iMac shuts down during startup

Tags: macos, imac, startup

I'm experiencing a shutdown of an iMac during startup, when the progression bar almost halfway.

I tried, with no success:
- starting up from the iMac recovery partition and checking the HD with Disk Utility (rebuilt permission, verified the HD)
- Safe Boot
- Fsck

Before attempting to reinstall Mac OS I think I need to backup the iMac first.

Any other check suggested before trying to re-install Mac OS?

Thanks for any insight!

Answer (score 1):

To attempt to back it up you could try starting in [Target Disk mode](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/mchlp1443/mac) & connect it to another Mac.

It is *potentially* safe - as you've checked the disk already with no errors - to simply overlay a new OS on top of the existing one without disturbing any other data. Run 'Install macOS' from the Recovery partition.

Comment: Tetsujin, thanks for your feedback. I still have problems: I'm unable to start the Mac OS install from the Recovery, since my Apple ID+password is not being recongnized (although it works on other Macs in my office :-( ).

Comment: Tetsujin, since my Apple ID/password are not recognized by the iMac, can I run the "install macOS" from the Terminal ? Beware that I don't want to erase the HD with its data, just "overlay a new OS on top of the existing one without disturbing any other data" as you say.

Comment: You shouldn't nee ID/pass from Recovery. Are you sure it didn't go to Internet Recovery instead?